# Search Between 2 Dates from Date as well as text search query

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried looking for a solution, i am very new to PHP and although i've looked, there does not seem to be a solution to help with the data formatting.

I am not too concerned about SQL injections and security as of yet with this as it is for an assignment to hand in, just some advice on how get the results i need.

I have a page where i am wanting to search for a keyword in a database, but also optional i would like to add a time frame search.

for example i can search for name, doctor, condition and medication by using the text search, but i would also optionally (as i would like to be able to search without using the date restriction) like to use the search appdatefrom and appdateto to narrow down appointment dates.

I am getting there error

> SQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE visitdate BETWEEN '2001-01-01' and '2015-01-01' ORDER BY visitdate ASC' at line 5

Currently in the database my visitdate are formatted as 2014-04-20 01:23:43

i am finding it hard to do, due to the time TIMESTAMP format.

Database looks as follows. i cannot get a good ERD with XAMP for some reason? so i have created one.

[Visit Table Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnpos.jpg)

[Database Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttEDW.png)

code for the page is as follows.

```
    <?php // Include config file
include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/freddies/inc/config.php");
include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/freddies/inc/functions.php");
include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/freddies/inc/header.php");

$sql  = "SELECT patient.fName AS fname, patient.sName AS surname, doctor.sName AS doc, conditions.con_name AS con, drugs.medication AS meds, visit.visitdate, visit.visit_id AS visitid  FROM visit 
            JOIN patient ON visit.patient_id = patient.patient_id
            JOIN doctor ON visit.doctor_id = doctor.doctor_id
            LEFT JOIN conditions ON visit.con_id = conditions.con_id
            LEFT JOIN drugs ON visit.drugs_id = drugs.med_id";

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

$search_term = ($_POST['searchapp']);
$appdatefrom = ($_POST['appdatefrom']);
$appdateto = ($_POST['appdateto']);

$sql .= " WHERE patient.fName LIKE '%".$search_term."%'";
$sql .= " OR patient.sName LIKE '%".$search_term."%'";
$sql .= " OR doctor.sName LIKE '%".$search_term."%'";
$sql .= " OR conditions.con_name LIKE '%".$search_term."%'";
$sql .= " OR drugs.medication LIKE '%".$search_term."%'";
$sql .= " WHERE visitdate BETWEEN '".$appdatefrom."' and '".$appdateto."'";
$sql .= " ORDER BY visitdate ASC";
}

$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

if (!$query) {
  die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($db));
  }

?>

<body>
<div class="container"><br><br>
<?php include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/freddies/inc/logo.html"); ?>

  <h2>APPOINTMENTS</h2>

  <p>Search Recent Appointments:</p>      

    <form name="searchform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <label>Search for Patient, Doctor, Medication or Condition</label> 
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="searchapp" placeholder="Example. Dr Mears, Tonsillitis, Vimovo, Andrew" required><br>
                    </div>   
                    <div class="col-xs-4">                         
                            <label>Date From:</label> 
                            <input type="date"  class="form-control" name="appdatefrom"><br>
                    </div>   
                    <div class="col-xs-4"> 
                            <label>Date To:</label> 
                            <input type="date"  class="form-control" name="appdateto"><br> 
                    </div>   
                    <div class="col-xs-4">                            
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="search" value="Submit">
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>      



  <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Patient Name</th>
        <th>Doctor</th>
        <th>Condition</th>
        <th>Medication Prescribed</th>
        <th>Visit ID</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        $no     = 1;
        $total  = 0;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
        {
            echo '<tr>
                    <td>'.$row['fname']." ".$row['surname'].'</td> 
                    <td>'."Dr ".$row['doc'].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$row['con'].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$row['meds'].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$row['visitid'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['visitdate'].'</td>
                    <td><a href="viewapp.php?id='.($row['visitid']).'" class="btn btn-warning pull-right btn-xs">View</a></td> 
                    <td><a href="delapp.php?id='.($row['visitid']).'" class="btn btn-danger pull-right btn-xs">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>';    
            $no++;
        }?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <a href="newapp.php" class="btn btn-success pull-left">New Appointment</a>
  <a href="" class="btn btn-info pull-left">Refesh</a>
  <a href="../" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Admin Area</a>
</div>
<div class="bottompadding"></div>
<?php include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/freddies/inc/footer.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

After looking at answers given, adding parenthasis in the code stopped it from working, it is currently working like this but without the date search?

this is how the site looks currently. when typing in my surname it brings up my results, but if i want to search between two dates it just does not do anything.
[Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m80a.jpg)

```
<?php // Include config file
include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/freddies/inc/config.php");
include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/freddies/inc/functions.php");
include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/freddies/inc/header.php");

$sql  = "SELECT patient.fName AS fname, patient.sName AS surname, doctor.sName AS doc, conditions.con_name AS con, drugs.medication AS meds, visit.visitdate, visit.visit_id AS visitid  FROM visit 
            JOIN patient ON visit.patient_id = patient.patient_id
            JOIN doctor ON visit.doctor_id = doctor.doctor_id
            LEFT JOIN conditions ON visit.con_id = conditions.con_id
            LEFT JOIN drugs ON visit.drugs_id = drugs.med_id";

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {

$search_term = ($_POST['searchapp']);
$appdatefrom = ($_POST['appdatefrom']);
$appdateto = ($_POST['appdateto']);

$sql .= " WHERE patient.fName LIKE '%".$search_term."%'";
$sql .= " OR patient.sName LIKE '%".$search_term."%'";
$sql .= " OR doctor.sName LIKE '%".$search_term."%'";
$sql .= " OR conditions.con_name LIKE '%".$search_term."%'";
$sql .= " OR drugs.medication LIKE '%".$search_term."%'";
$sql .= " AND visitdate BETWEEN '".$appdatefrom."' and '".$appdateto."'";
$sql .= " ORDER BY visitdate ASC";
}

$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

if (!$query) {
  die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($db));
  }

?>

<body>
<div class="container"><br><br>
<?php include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/freddies/inc/logo.html"); ?>

  <h2>APPOINTMENTS</h2>

  <p>Search Recent Appointments:</p>      

    <form name="searchform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <label>Search for Patient, Doctor, Medication or Condition</label> 
                            <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="searchapp" placeholder="Example. Dr Mears, Tonsillitis, Vimovo, Andrew" required><br>
                    </div>   
                    <div class="col-xs-4">                         
                            <label>Date From:</label> 
                            <input type="date"  class="form-control" name="appdatefrom"><br>
                    </div>   
                    <div class="col-xs-4"> 
                            <label>Date To:</label> 
                            <input type="date"  class="form-control" name="appdateto"><br> 
                    </div>   
                    <div class="col-xs-4">                            
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="search" value="Submit">
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>      



  <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Patient Name</th>
        <th>Doctor</th>
        <th>Condition</th>
        <th>Medication Prescribed</th>
        <th>Visit ID</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        $no     = 1;
        $total  = 0;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
        {
            echo '<tr>
                    <td>'.$row['fname']." ".$row['surname'].'</td> 
                    <td>'."Dr ".$row['doc'].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$row['con'].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$row['meds'].'</td> 
                    <td>'.$row['visitid'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['visitdate'].'</td>
                    <td><a href="viewapp.php?id='.($row['visitid']).'" class="btn btn-warning pull-right btn-xs">View</a></td> 
                    <td><a href="delapp.php?id='.($row['visitid']).'" class="btn btn-danger pull-right btn-xs">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>';    
            $no++;
        }?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <a href="newapp.php" class="btn btn-success pull-left">New Appointment</a>
  <a href="" class="btn btn-info pull-left">Refesh</a>
  <a href="../" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Admin Area</a>
</div>
<div class="bottompadding"></div>
<?php include("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/freddies/inc/footer.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use parameterized queries. That will take care of quoting issues as well as prevent SQL Injection. Also it's really simple to format dates in PHP. Lookup the date() function.

Comment: i have updated questions with the error code i am getting.

also im not too concerned at this moment with SQL injections etc as this is just for an assignment.

Comment: Ok, so how have you defined the `visitdate` in your schema

Comment: You can't have two WHEREs.

Comment: Ohhhh geeeezzzzz I have been staring at that for ages and completely missed it. DUH @Don'tPanic

Comment: i have added schema

Comment: See the answer from @Don'tPanic , that is your problem! Dont forget to upvote the answer and accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have one WHERE clause per query. If you want to combine the date range with the search, use AND with a parenthesized set of OR conditions.

```
$sql .= " WHERE visitdate BETWEEN '".$appdatefrom."' and '".$appdateto."'";
$sql .= " AND (patient.fName LIKE '%".$search_term."%'";
$sql .= " OR patient.sName LIKE '%".$search_term."%'";
$sql .= " OR doctor.sName LIKE '%".$search_term."%'";
$sql .= " OR conditions.con_name LIKE '%".$search_term."%'";
$sql .= " OR drugs.medication LIKE '%".$search_term."%')";
$sql .= " ORDER BY visitdate ASC";
```

Using parentheses will specify that `a AND b OR c OR d` will be evaluated as `a AND (b OR c OR d)` rather than `(a AND b) OR c OR d`.

Comment: i have changed it to AND and when imputting dates. it kind of ignores the dates i have put in and just shows all data searched in first box regardless of dates.?

Comment: Did you combine all the ORs in parentheses? That's generally necessary for this kind of combined AND/OR condition to work.

Comment: I have done it as you have said and it is now not showing any results? i dont know if im missing something.

Comment: I'm not sure. I answered based on the original code in your question, with the general cause of the syntax error you were getting then, and showing how you can combine AND with multiple OR conditions, but it's difficult to debug from there without seeing what's changed in your code since then, knowing what your inputs are and what's in your database, etc.

Comment: i have tried adding 

$sql .= " AND visitdate BETWEEN CAST('".$appdatefrom."' AS DATE) AND CAST('".$appdateto."' AS DATE)";

but this is dpomthe same?